# Multilingual model in DDD

Tags: php, domain-driven-design

I am working in a project we we use DDD and now we want to implement localisation for some fields.

Example:

```
<?php

class Product 
{
    private $id;
    private $name;

    public function __construct($id, $name)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
    }   
}
```

I have a service to create this product:

Example:

```
<?php 

class CreateProductService
{
    private $productRepository;

    public function __construct($productRepository)
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function execute(CreateProductRequest $request)
    {
        $product = new Product(
            $request->getId(),
            $request->getName(),
        );

        $this->productRepository->create($product);
    }
}
```

Then now I want to change the request DTO to get names instead of name because from the form now I get these:

```
$names = [
    'es' => 'Name in spanish',
    'en' => 'Name in english',
    ...
]
```

What is the best approach to achieve this?

I have read on the internet that is not a good practice to have in the model Product an array of names then what do you suggest?

Thanks.

Comment: Where exactly do you need the localization? Only in the UI?

Comment: Well I have it in the database.

For example

`product (id)
product_lang (product_id, name, locale)`

Then it's in the UI and also on the database.

Comment: In your case it seems like localization is not a business concern, thus should not be part od the domain model.

Comment: David Packer, can you provide me an example? Thanks very much...

Comment: He means that DDD doesn't care about your localization; it's an *implementation detail.*  There's no example to provide, because you won't use DDD to design it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it this way:

- Have a class Product that defines all the core properties of the thing; everything that is independent from country, language or currency of the user.
- Then, have a `ProductDescriptor`. One for each language.

---

```
class Product {
    private $id;
    private $categories;
    // ...

    private $descriptors;
}

class ProductDescriptor {
    private $product;
    private $locale;

    private $name;
    private $description;
    private $price;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

But I have a GetProductsService that I get the products with only one name, and not translations....

Maybe should I keep the name in the Product too?

Thanks

Comment: The `name` is your primary key??

Comment: No it's the id.

Comment: So whats the issue then? Fetch the product by ID and construct the descriptor objects for it. You dont *have to* read them from the DB.

Comment: @marstato indeed, you can store them in a format that makes the most sense for this use.